# autocomplete.js exclude words from triggering search

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using http://autocompletejs.com/ and my client is asking if certain words can be excluded, or as they say, "treated as neutral", and not trigger the autocomplete box from displaying.

In other words, let's say the following items are in my list:

- Tree Green
- Tree Red
- Tree Real
- Tree Fake
- Tree Tall
- Tree Trunk
- Plant Green
- Plant Bush

They want the results to display with Tree/Plant as the first word, but typing Tree or Plant should not trigger the list.  The user would have to type "Tree R" before any results appear.  Or they can type "R" to see the results that contain R in the second word.

I can't set minLength because they also want the user to be able to enter "Re" to see the Red/Real results.

Another way around this would be ignoring the first word of all items on my list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can set the preProcess option:
http://autocompletejs.com/examples#2003

Or probably more correct option would be the matchOptions option:
http://autocompletejs.com/examples#4041

In the case of the latter, the idea is to figure out how many spaces are in the user's search term and then return only the results with the same amount of spaces.

NOTE: You will also want to trim the user's input to make sure you do not get errant results. I will assume you are using jQuery since .trim does not have full browser compatibility, but feel free to implement your own trim method in the line below the comment.

```
var matchOptions = function(input, matchedOptions, allOptions, value) {
    // NOTE: be sure to trim the input first.
    var term = $.trim(input)
        spacesInSearchTerm = term.split(" ").length,
        validOptions = [];

    for (var i = 0, l = matchedOptions.length; i < l; i ++) {
        if (matchedOptions[i].split(" ").length === spacesInSearchTerm)
            validList.push(list[l]);
    }

    return validOptions;
};
```